# Selecting users in a SQL Server database which have only default children

Tags: sql-server, select, hierarchy

I'm trying to figure out how many users in my database have default parameters. I've got the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
  FROM Users
  JOIN Streams ON Users.Id = Streams.UserId
  JOIN Playlists ON Streams.Id = Playlists.StreamId
  WHERE Playlists.FirstItemId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

I thought this was fine, but I realized that this is not specific enough. Currently, a Stream with 2 Playlists, one populated and one not, is still selected. I would like to not select a Stream if any of its child Playlists have a FirstItemId set to a value other than '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.

This additional select is a bit beyond me.. I've tried for some time, but can't get the syntax. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: would you mind providing sample data and expected output in sqlfiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT TOP 4000 Users.Id
  FROM Users
  JOIN (SELECT Playlists.StreamId FROM Streams JOIN Playlists ON Streams.Id = Playlists.StreamId
        GROUP BY Playlists.StreamID HAVING MAX(CAST(Playlists.FirstItemId as VARCHAR(36)) = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') as StreamPlaylists
ON Users.Id = StreamPlaylists.UserId
```

You need a grouped subquery on Playlists and Streams.  Selecting playlists where the maximum `FirstItemId` is '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' excludes those with other (higher sorted) GUIDs.  GUIDs can't be `MIN`/`MAX`ed, thus the `CAST` to `VARCHAR`.